# Для чего в данном коде использовать parse ? И что он вообще делает?

Tags: java

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date myDate = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat sdfOne = new SimpleDateFormat("'Today is' dd/MM/yyyy");

        String myDay = "Today is 17/01/2000";

        try {
            myDate = sdfOne.parse(myDay);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String result = sdfOne.format(myDate);
        System.out.println(result);

        System.out.println(myDate.getTime());

    }

}
```

Comment: скорее всего попытка преобразовать текст в дату. А если преобразование не успешно - то использовать дату по-умолчанию. То есть результат мы получим в любом случае. А если бы не было этого блока и была бы ошибка в `myDay` - то получили бы исключение

Comment: От меня минус. Это базовые понятия на любом ЯП. В комментарии выше вам ответили.

Comment: я так понимаю вы взяли чей-то код и присвоили его себе? Нее, у нас так не пройдет. От меня минус

Comment: Всегда можно посмотреть вывод результат в System.out.println и сделать выводы. Всегда можно попробовать стереть этот parse и посмотреть, что будет с кодом без него. Так что странный вопрос какой-то

Comment: Всегда можно просто почитать документацию.

Answer (score 5):

`Date myDate = new Date();` - создает и устанавливает текущее (в момент выполнения комманды) время в переменную `myDate`

`myDate = sdfOne.parse(myDay);` - устанавливает время `myDay` согласно формату `sdfOne` в переменную `myDate`

---

Давайте проанализируем то, что вывелось в консоль

> Today is 17/01/2000
>
> 948060000000

В первой строке мы видим понятный и читабельный для человека формат даты, сформатированный по Вашему шаблону, а во второй - формат даты `Date`, полученный методом `getTime` и понятный для чтения компьютеру. `948060000000` - количество миллисекунд, прошедших с момента полуночи 1 января 1970. Так компьютер понимает время.

Таким образом, чтоб передать компьютеру информацию о дате, мы вынуждены обьяснить ему в каком именно формате мы ему ее передаем (`sdfOne`) и что с етим форматом делать - `parse` (парсить).

**Вывод**

> метод `parse` парсит данные пользователя из пользовательского формата в формат `Date`

Чтоб немного добавить понятности - добавим один день к Вашей дате следующим способом:

- 1 день = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 86400000 мс

  ```
  System.out.println(myDate);

  final long ONE_DAY = 24*60*60*1000;
  long newDate = myDate.getTime() + ONE_DAY;

  myDate.setTime(newDate);

  System.out.println(myDate);
  ```

результат:

> Mon Jan 17 00:00:00 EET 2000
>
> Tue Jan 18 00:00:00 EET 2000

Comment: Parse парсит - звучит как то не по русски :)\

Comment: @Barmaley если дословно перевести - "анализирует", то как-то не подходит для обьяснения, т.к. оно не просто анализирует. А вот в моем кругу общения такой термин почему-то прижился)